Looking for explanation how SpamAssassin communicates with mail server
Our server runs Exim for MTA and we also installed and activated SpamAssassin under DirectAdmin for all users and mailboxes. Most of our users use Gmail or Apple mail to access the server's mailboxes via IMAP.
I'm kind of newby in this field. My big question is, what happens if a user marks an email as spam:

Does Gmail or Apple mail communicate that back to SpamAssassin on the server?
And if so, does SpamAssassin communicate that back to the cloud, like a SpamAssassin cloud based database?

I would be happy with any links that provide more in-depth explanations how this functions. Could not find any myself...
